# Decreasing verbosity: inserting elements into map

Tags: c++, c++11, verbosity, code-formatting

I've been getting familiar with C++11 lately, and the `auto` keyword is great! Typing:

```
for (auto bar : bars) {
```

is oh-so satisfying. Keeps code readable and pretty. What still feels like it stops all your momentum is the following:

```
foo.insert(std::pair<std::string, bar>("soVerbose", baz));

// As opposed to simply:

foo.insert("soVerbose", baz);
```

Is there a good reason it is the way it is? And is there some neat way of making it less verbose? I know the `[]` operator can be used for inserting elements into maps, but the functionality is slightly different.

Comment: You could `typedef std::pair<std::string, bar> tDataPair;` which would make the code slightly more readable like so `foo.insert(tDataPair("soVerbose", baz));`

Comment: I agree that `auto` _can_ be used irresponsibly, but I don't see the harm in using it to avoid writing a long declaration type for a data type that can be easily inferred.

Comment: @EdHeal: And using C++ tells me that the developer isn't thinking about assembly at all. I'm failing to see the problem.

Comment: What you actually meant to write was `foo.insert(std::make_pair("soVerbose", baz));` anyway.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use the [emplace](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/emplace) function:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

#include <map>

int main()
{
    std::map<std::string, std::string> m;

    // uses pair's copy-constructor
    m.emplace(std::make_pair(std::string("a"), std::string("a")));

    // uses pair's converting copy constructor
    m.emplace(std::make_pair("b", "abcd"));

    // uses pair's template constructor
    m.emplace("d", "ddd");

    // uses pair's piecewise constructor
    m.emplace(std::piecewise_construct,
              std::forward_as_tuple("c"),
              std::forward_as_tuple(10, 'c'));

    for (const auto &p : m) {
        std::cout << p.first << " => " << p.second << '\n';
    }
}
```

Comment: It's only courteous to quote your sources. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/emplace word for word.

Comment: @polkadotcadaver: Yes, I already have a link to that page in the answer.

Answer (score 11):

You can use `std::make_pair()` which makes it, at least, a bit better:

```
foo.insert(std::make_pair("soVerbose", baz));
```

Actually, I'm not entirely sure whether this is meant to work but I think it is (the reason I'm not quite sure is that `"soVerbose"` could be deduced as `char const[10]` and the type `char const[10]` isn't copyable; that was an error, at least, in some implementation at some point). I'm not, yet, using C++11 enough but I *think* you can also use

```
foo.insert({ "notSoVerbose", baz });
```

(the code certainly compiles with [gcc](http://gcc.gnu.org/) and [clang](http://clang.llvm.org/)).

I see others already mentioned it but actually, you'd really use:

```
foo.emplace("pretty cool", baz);
```

Comment: `std::make_pair` performs a `decay_copy` on the arguments, turning the array into a pointer.

Answer (score 5):

You can use make_pair, it will deduce the types of the pair's elements without you having to state them so verbosely:

```
foo.insert(std::make_pair("soVerbose", baz));
```

But, also, if you're using C++11 (a recent visual studio, for example), you should prefer using emplace:

```
foo.emplace("soVerbose", baz);
```

Comment: Why `make_pair` if you're using `emplace`? `emplace` can forward ctor arguments.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Just as I was typing the edit :)

Comment: Nice :) BTW even the most recent Visual Studio CTP has somewhat pathetic C++11 support. Clang or GCC 4.8 would be better examples, arguably.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit *"pathetic"* would be the wrong word, especially when talking about the features in this question (and given your definition of *"most recent"* matches mine).

Answer (score 0):

To decrease verbosity write

```
foo.emplace("soVerbose", baz);
```